# Determine the best cup of coffee to have faster cooling possible

Tags: surfaces, volume

Assume that a cup of coffee is a cylinder.
The coffee machine at my workplace always produces the same amount of coffee, so the volume is constant.
The coffee is always really hot, so I'm looking (out of curiosity) to maximize the cooling effect of the cup. If the coffee has a bigger contact area, it will transfer more heat per unit of time. Assume that the amount of heat per time transferred with cup and air are the same, or consider a "closed cup", for example. Assume it is not relevant.

I have some cups to choose from.
What is cup that provides the biggest contact area (with air and cup), given that the volume is the same?

Theoretically I know that we could either have:

- a *1 atom height cylinder with a large radius* **or**
- a *half atom radius with a large height*.

However these are some extreme and particular cases.
I'm looking for a general formal proof that could give me some rationale for my choice.

Something like "you should choose whatever cup has more radius/height",etc.

Sorry for any possible lack of formality. This is my first question here. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "cooling area" is given by $2\pi r^2 + 2\pi rh = 2\pi r(r+h)$
So the optimal choice is the cup with the biggest value of $r(r+h)$ and fixed volume $V = \pi r^2 h \Rightarrow h = V/\pi \cdot r^{-2}$,
$$r^{\text{opt}} = \mathop{\rm arg\,max}_{r>0} r^2 + V/\pi \cdot \frac1r = \mathop{\rm arg\,max}_{r>0} r^3 = +\infty$$
Answer: Take the biggest radius.

Comment: How did you go from

$\mathop{\rm arg\,max}_{r>0} r^2 + V/\pi \cdot \frac1r $

*to*

$ \mathop{\rm arg\,max}_{r>0} r^3 = +\infty$
?

Also, it feels a bit counter intuitive that I only need to consider the radius when looking at the biggest surface area, right?

Comment: @miguelcobain note that the height is prescribed by the radius via constant volume. All I did was multiply by $r>0$, wich works due to the asymptotics, you can also leave that step out to see that the LHS is $+\infty$, but that requires a bit more calculations (See that the derivative $2r-\frac V\pi \frac1{r^2}$ only has one root at $\sqrt[3]{\frac V{2\pi}}$ and argue why you don't have a maximum there).

Comment: @miguelcobain Also note that a coin (big radius, small height) has a much greater surface than a wire (small radius, big height / length)

Comment: Basically, increasing the radius prevails over increasing the height? I see. I'm just not understanding why we suddenly have a $r^3$. What exactly happened to the $ r^2 + V/\pi \cdot \frac1r $ part?

Comment: Also, that analogy of the coin and wire only works when the volume is constant, right?

Comment: @miguelcobain Multiply by $r$ and note that $\max_x f(x) + C = \max_x f(x)$. And yes, you need that constant volume to enforce a relationship between $r$ and $h$. Else you could just let $h$ explode and leave $r$ constant. (You get a coin vs. a pipe)